# Usage of "down" as a preposition and adverb

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

What does *down* mean in these statements?

As a preposition:

> She was walking **down** the street.

As an adverb:

> to go **down** to Miami/Florida.

Comment: Juan, in both instances ***down*** is a Preposition. In the first sentence it's a Transitive Preposition, and in the second sentence it's an Intransitive Proposition. In the first sentence the complement of the preposition is a Noun Phrase - *the street*. In the second sentence the preposition doesn't take any complement. The verb - *go* - takes two complements - two Preposition Phrases. The first complement is realized by the preposition - *down* - only. And the other complement is - *to Miami/Florida*.

Comment: Don't over-think this one. In most contexts, to *walk **down / up / along** the street* are interchangeable and all mean exactly the same thing. The matter of whether there's a gradient in the road (in either direction of travel) is rarely relevant to the choice of preposition.

Comment: To go down to Miami means you were in a place located north of the city. From Miami, you would go up [by car] to New York. NY is north of Miami. And bonus: if a city is east or west of you, you might say over: I'm going over to Nashville this afternoon.

Comment: You can look *down the barrel* of a gun even if it's pointed up at a bird in flight. In such contexts, **down** means **along**.

Comment: See [*down*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/down_1):  "5. preposition - If you go or look down something such as a road or river, you go or look along it. If you are down a road or river, you are somewhere along it." and "6. adverb - If you are travelling to a particular place, you can say that you are going down to that place, especially if you are going towards the south or to a lower level of land."